# handlebars mongoose express

Tags: mongoose, view, handlebars.js

i am totally bignner my data in mongo db is  that i want to extract one by one.i am able to fech Question and Answer but how i  fetch data from access[] plz help me

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c6442cdbaab553cae9913d"),
    "Qno" : 1,
    "Question" : "who u rqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
    "Answer" : "fineqqqqqqqqqqq",
    "answerr" : {
        "option" : "hi i ",
        "option" : "hi i "
    },
    "access" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "Printer"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "name" : "Desktop"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "4",
            "name" : "VMs"
        }
    ]
}
```

i have data on mongodb and i want to fetch data fropm it so i use

```
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // res.render('index');
    UserData.find()
        .then(function(doc) {
            //res.json({ 'items': doc });
            res.render('rnglishonelinear', { 'items': doc });

        });
    console.log('hiu');

});
```

handlebars to handle it

```
<section class="get2" draggable="true" (click)="">

    {{# each items as |p index|}}          

                {{p.access.name}}
                    <br>
                    {{Question}}

                  <br>option:{{item.access.name}}
                name::    {{this.access}}

{{#each access}}
  {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```